# Why did Bender go to the suicide booth initially in Space Pilot 3000

Tags: futurama

What was the initial reason that drove Bender to a suicide booth in the first place?

Comment: I don't think this should have been closed, this is a good question.

Answer (score 5):

He found out that the girders he was bending were being used to make suicide booths.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto It's stated in the first episode.

Answer (score 2):

Bender found out that the   girders that he was bending were being used to make suicide booths.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?